# How to Disable selector in file

Tags: css

I have a `style.css` file. that has

```
.example {
  float: none;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}
```

now, I try to disable some attribute in `.example` class to

```
.example {
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

I try like below but that's not working

```
<style type="text/css">
          .example {
                bottom: 20px !important;
                top: none !important;
                left: none !important;
                position: none !important;
            }
 </style>
```

Is that posible? I don't want to change direct in file?

Answer (score 1):

The properties you are trying to overwrite it with are not valid.

[image]

There is no such thing as `position:none`, `top:none`, and `left:none`..

Instead, use something like:

```
.example {
    bottom:20px;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    position:static;
}
```

Doing this will successfully overwrite each property and set it back to its defaults.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nMNBC/)

Using `auto` will essentially reset the properties to their initial value, **no need for** `!important`.

Aside from merely overwriting properties, you could always just remove them to begin with too - most of the time...

Comment: Snap.  You wouldn't need the left and top rules though because they won't affect the position of an element that is 'static'.

Comment: @davidpauljunior You are correct - I just wanted to show how to set those back to defaults anyways. Using auto wouldn't require static either.

Comment: `position:static;` fail in my case, is possible to remove `position` ?

Comment: @freestyle If you provide an example, i'd be happy to show you.

Comment: if change `position` to any value then my form not correct. If disable `position`, then that working. But is possible to remove that. My example is hard to make a example to view :(

Comment: @freestyle Have you tried just removing `position:static`, using `auto` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you declare that style in the HTML in your  AFTER you import style.css, it should take precedence.

See this here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruXXc/2/)

```
<p>Some Text</p>  <!-- takes most recent styling of <p> -->
```

I am importing a stylesheet with a paragraph background of blue, but I re-declare it in my CSS to be red.  The redeclared one takes precedence, as it is declared later.

Note too your CSS is not valid.  Should be something like:

```
.example {
    bottom: 20px !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    position: static !important;
}
```

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp
and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: I noticed the errors in the CSS after I posted my answer, didn't bother to read yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.example { position: static; }`.

'None' is not a valid value for these CSS rules.  Once you set the position to static, top, bottom, left, right won't matter any more.  'Static' is the default value for the 'position' rule.

Answer (score 0):

`top: none;` , `left: none;`, `position: none;` these are not a valid CSS properties.

You can try with this:

```
.example {
    bottom:20px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:static; /*static*/  /*absolute*/ /*relative*/  /*fixed*/;
}
```